Why is my translation not prioritizing the glossary content?
google document:https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#v3
I am currently using Google Glossary Translate.
I added a glossary and the content is
{
  "glossaryEntries": [
    {
      "name": "projects/521859549804/locations/us-central1/glossaries/test-1-zh-CN-en/glossaryEntries/719985033120439992",
      "termsSet": {
        "terms": [
          {
            "languageCode": "zh-CN",
            "text": "叶新"
          },
          {
            "languageCode": "en",
            "text": "Sammy Yare"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


I translate text with a glossary, the translation content added is
function getContent(){
    return '
这么维护叶新”
叶新朝它
叶新冲过去
叶新乐呵呵
';
}

The result is
{
  "translations": [
    {
      "translatedText": "\r\nSeeing Long Yalin defending Ye Xin so much, she let go of Ye Xin, and then said to Ye Xin: &quot;Ye Xin, right? Remember my name! My name is Li Tianyu!&quot; Ye Xin shot at it. Ye Xin rushed over and hugged her. Ye Xin was happy.\r\n"
    }
  ],
  "glossaryTranslations": [
    {
      "translatedText": "\r\nSeeing Long Yalin defending Sammy Yare so much, she let go of Sammy Yare, and then said to Sammy Yare: &quot;Sammy Yare, right? Remember my name! My name is Li Tianyu!&quot; Ye Xin shot at it. Ye Xin rushed over and hugged her. Ye Xin was happy.\r\n",
      "glossaryConfig": {
        "glossary": "projects/521859549804/locations/us-central1/glossaries/test-1-zh-CN-en"
      }
    }
  ]
}


It is obvious to see

"叶新朝它" is translated into "Ye Xin shot at it"
"叶新冲过去" is translated into "Ye Xin rushed over and hugged her"
"叶新乐呵呵" is translated into "Ye Xin was happy"

What I want should be

"叶新朝它" is translated into "Sammy Yare shot at it"
"叶新冲过去" is translated into "Sammy Yare rushed over and hugged her"
"叶新乐呵呵" is translated into "Sammy Yare was happy"

Only the first translation is correct.
The execution code is as follows
function curlTranslateText($glossaryId,$contents,$sourceLanguageCode,$targetLanguageCode){
    $url = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/'.$GLOBALS["projectId"].'/locations/us-central1:translateText';
    $data = [
        "sourceLanguageCode" => $sourceLanguageCode,
        "targetLanguageCode" => $targetLanguageCode,
        "contents" => $contents,
        "glossaryConfig" => [
            "glossary" => "projects/".$GLOBALS["projectId"]."/locations/us-central1/glossaries/".$glossaryId,
            "ignoreCase" => false,
        ]
    ];
    $res = google_auth_curl($url,"POST",json_encode($data),getHeader());
    echo $res;
    exit();
}

How should I set up this kind of problem?
How to prioritize glossary content during translation
